# Probability that elements in a noncommutative group commute

Tags: group-theory

We consider $G$, a noncommutative group which contains $n$ elements.

Show the probability that $2$ elements of $G$ commute is lower than $\frac{5}{8}$.

Comment: Seems to be Theorem 1.7 of [this note that showed up by a search](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2010/SeniorProject_CodyClifton.pdf).

Comment: Paragraph 2 of that paper states exactly the result you want to prove,  and claims that the paper contains a proof.