# Show that the probability that two randomly choosen elements from $R$ commute is at most $(5/8)$.

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite non-commutative ring. Show that the probability that
two randomly choosen elements
from $R$ commute is at most
$(5/8)$.

i know there is an answer in https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/SeniorProjectArchive/2010/SeniorProject_CodyClifton.pdf

But I can't get it. Can anyone please give me any new answer or explain what is written here explicitly.

Comment: Maybe a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/950815/75923) can help.

Answer (score 1):

the key idea is that if $a,b$ are chosen at random from $G$ then they commute iff $b$ belongs to $Z_G(a)$, the centralizer of $a$. thus since conjugates share the same centralizer, the probability that $b$ commutes with $gag^{-1}$ is also
$$
p(a,b) = \frac{Z_G(a)}{|G|}=[G:Z_G(a)]^{-1}
$$
since each $a$ is equally likely to be chosen with probability $|G|^{-1}$ we find the probability of two elements commuting is
$$
|G|^{-1}\sum_{a \in G} [G:Z_G(a)]^{-1}
$$
since the sum can be done over conjugacy classes this shows that the probability we require is in fact simply
$$\frac{C_G}{|G|}$$

where $C_G$ is the number of conjugacy classes of $G$

since every element of the center is a class, and any other class must have at least two elements in it, we have:
$$
C_G \le |Z(G)| + \frac12(|G|-|Z|) = \frac12(|G|+|Z(G)|)
$$
an easy argument shows that the index of the center of a non-abelian group must be at least $4$, from which the result follows.

Comment: This seems to answer the question for a finite nonabelian group, where inverses always exist. Why does it work for a finite noncommutative ring, where (multiplicative) inverses may not exist?