# Is the order of this group bounded?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group,
$C(G)$ be a center of $G$, and centralizer of a subset $\{a\}$ (provided $a$ is not an element of $C(G)$) be $C(a)$.

Then, the order of $G$ which satisfies $\#C(G)=2$ and $\#C(a)=\#G/2$ is bounded?

This question is inspired from [Probability that $xy = yx$ for random elements in a finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950815/probability-that-xy-yx-for-random-elements-in-a-finite-group)

If $G$'s order is not bounded, we can say even if we choose two elements from $G$ by not allowing duplication and an identity element, we can say the upper bound of $P(G)$ is $5/8$.

Comment: I'm not sure about your question, but it seems that extraspecial 2-groups satisfy the required conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me why does the second condition is satisfied?

Comment: @DerekHolt That violates the first condition.

Comment: Yes you are right! I suspect that that extraspecial 2-groups are the only examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as follows.

> Is there a constant $U$ that if $G$ is a finite group with the center $C(G)$ of order two and centralizers $C(a)$ of index two for every $a \in G \setminus C(G)$, then the order of $G$ is bounded above by $U$?

The answer to the above question is *negative*; and extraspecial $2$-groups provide a counterexample. Since such a group has the center of order two and the order is not bounded, all we have to prove is that the indices of centralizers of non-central elements equal two.

Let $G$ be an extraspecial $2$-group with center $C(G) = \langle t \rangle$ and $a \in G \setminus C(G)$. Because $G' = C(G)$, we have $[a, g] \in \langle t \rangle$ for every element $g \in G$. In other words, a map
$$ \phi \colon G \to G', \quad g \mapsto [a, g]$$
is surjective. Hence $G = \phi^{-1}(1) \sqcup \phi^{-1}(t)$. As $\phi^{-1}(1) = C(a)$, we need to investigate what $\phi^{-1}(t)$ is. Let $b \in G \setminus C(a)$. Note that $[a, b] = t$. We claim that $\phi^{-1}(t) = bC(a)$. Suppose $g \in bC(a)$ and write $g = bc$ for some $c \in C(a)$. Then 
$$[a, g] = [a, bc] = c^{-1}[a, b]c = c^{-1}tc = t.$$
Hence $g \in \phi^{-1}(t)$.

Next, suppose $g \in \phi^{-1}(t)$. Then
$$
\begin{align*}
[a, b^{-1}g]
&= a^{-1}g^{-1}bab^{-1}g
= a^{-1}g^{-1}bab^{-1}(a^{-1}a)g\\
&= a^{-1}g^{-1}[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]ag
= a^{-1}g^{-1}ag[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]\\
&= [a, g][b^{-1}, a^{-1}]
= t[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]
= [a, b][b^{-1}, a^{-1}]\\
&= a^{-1}b^{-1}ab[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]
= a^{-1}b^{-1}[b^{-1}, a^{-1}]ab
= a^{-1}b^{-1}(bab^{-1}a^{-1})ab \\
&= 1.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore, $b^{-1}g \in \phi^{-1}(1) = C(a)$.

Now we proved that $G = C(a) \sqcup bC(a)$, so that $C(a)$ has index two.

Comment: Since all centralizers have index $1$ or $2$, for all $g,h \in G$, the elements $g^2$ and $[g,h]$ lie in the intersection of all centralizers, which is $Z(G)$. So $G$ is a $2$-group with $Z(G) = [G,G]$, where $|Z(G)|=2$ and $G/Z(G)$ is elementary abelian i.e. $G$ is an extraspecial 2-group. So these are the only examples.